# Why does this boost example not link on OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, boost, cmake

I have a very small example app that builds, links, and runs correctly on Ubuntu.  But when I try on OS X, I get link errors I cannot figure out.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
PROJECT ( Test C CXX )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED ( VERSION 2.8 )
SET ( Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON )
SET ( Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON )
SET ( Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex system date_time )
FIND_PACKAGE ( Threads REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ( AFTER ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
SET ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" )
ADD_EXECUTABLE ( myapp test.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( myapp ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

Here is my test.cpp file:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    boost::regex e( "he[^ ]{3} " );
    if (boost::regex_search( "hello world", e ))
    {
        std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running `cmake ..` works fine, it finds Boost version 1.57.0 and AppleClang 5.1.05030040.  But when I try to run `make` I get approximately 250 lines of errors, starting with:

```
Linking CXX executable myapp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(char const*, char const*, boost::match_results<char const*, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, char const*) in test.cpp.o
  "boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::find()", referenced from:
      bool boost::regex_search<char const*, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(char const*, char const*, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags) in test.cpp.o
  "std::string::compare(char const*) const", referenced from:
      unsigned int boost::re_detail::find_sort_syntax<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>, char>(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> const*, char*) in libboost_regex.a(instances.o)
```

I'm on OS X 10.8.5 [Mountain Lion] and using:

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

---

**Edit**:  As asked, here is the command with `VERBOSE=1`:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/test.cpp.o
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -I/usr/local/include    -o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/test.cpp.o -c /Users/Administrator/tmp/test.cpp
Linking CXX executable myapp
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.2.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/test.cpp.o  -o myapp  /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.a 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<char const*, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<char const*> >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
```

Comment: use VERBOSE=yes to get the linker line

Comment: @arved I've edited the question and added the verbose output where the link is failing.

Comment: How did you install Boost - you might not have a 64 bit library

Comment: I've tried both "brew install boost" and "sudo port install boost", with the same result.  (De-installing in between.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your Boost libraries were compiled with libstdc++, and you are building against libc++.

---

**Edit:**

To get Boost to use libc++ instead of libstdc++, install with:

```
brew install boost --c++11
```

To see if boost is linking against libc++ or libstdc++, try something like this:

```
otool -L /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib
```

Comment: Correct.  I ran `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib` and I can see it is linked against libstdc++.6.dylib.  What is the right solution:  is it to rebuild Boost with libc++?  Isn't libstdc++ the old way of doing things?

Comment: libstdc++ is not the old way, it is just as advanced as libc++ in terms of language support. It is the standard library used by gcc, and it can also be used by clang if you specify -stdlib=libstdc++. You can choose to go either way, but since you're on OS X the standard gcc there is 4.2 and libstdc++ is just as outdated. So unless you can use a more recent gcc it's probably better to use clang and libc++. If you can, though, gcc and libstdc++ would be preferred for better portability.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer, since Boost installed with homebrew using the default options is indeed linking against libstdc++.  To get Boost for libc++ (required if using C++11) you must install with: `brew install boost --c++11`.